# How to making ajax content crawlable by search engines

Tags: ajax, jquery, seo

I have a website that paginate result via jquery.ajax(). URLs looks like: `website.com/index.php?page=N`

I've googled and found some posts talking about it... so what i've understood is that i need to replace the "?" with "#!". It's that enought?

Besides, should i include in the sitemap a link for each page?

```
website.com/index.php (priority 1)
website.com/index.php#!page=2 (priority 0.9)
and so on...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best answer I can give on this is from the source, here's how Google prefers you make your AJAX content indexable: [Making AJAX Applications Crawlable](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/learn-more.html).

For your specific question about the URL piece, [start here](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html).

Comment: thanx! I just need to understand the part of _escaped_fragment_. If i'm not wrong i have to create a serverside script that return a static page with the content of ajax request when is called "website.com/index.php?_escaped_fragment_=page=2"

Comment: @Luciano - That's correct, so it can place the static result that goes with that ajax request into it's index/cache.

Comment: How about the other search engines out there? Is there a solution to make all search engines index ajax content?

Comment: @alexborbely - I don't know that they *all* follow a convention...but given google is the biggest source of traffic for most I'd say use their method and hope all others follow suit as it's most likely a standard later.

Comment: This recommendation is officially deprecated as of October 2015.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look to [The Single Page Interface Manifesto](http://itsnat.sourceforge.net/php/spim/spi_manifesto_en.php)

Answer (score 2):

paginated results are mostly non-landingpages and do not yield much SEO traffic and/or if you have a very very big site, can even hurt your SEO efforts. if you have other ways that google reaches your landingpages (i.e.: a sitemap and/or sitemap.xml) you could skip that topic altogether.