# Google Crwaling AJAX Application

Tags: ajax, jquery, seo

In my site , I added lot of AJAX function , For (dynamic pages ) ,

I read the below thread, i understand GOOGLE AJAX Crawler Procedure,

Just am confirming  ,

In applications am not used the  links,

i am  using   DIV, in that DIV  onclick  i called the ajax function  ,

in that ajax code there is a URL , in this URL i appended the #!key=value ,

Please confirm IT , its correct ?

Thanks

NOTE: I dont have  TAG ,

My sample Snippet,

```
url='mycaller.php?reid=12#!reid=12'
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlHttp.send(null);
```

[my reference url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839055/how-to-making-ajax-content-crawlable-by-search-engines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i confirm, that this is not the way it works.

google crawls

- mycaller.php?reid=12#!reid=12

as

- mycaller.php?reid=12&_escaped_fragment_=reid=12

you need to return an HTML response to the second URL. it's like cloaking (from a technology standpoint), but ok with google.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my

> [lens on squido](http://www.squidoo.com/ajax-crawling)

I tried to explain how ajax crawling works in more details.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.