# creating javascript widget that is SEO friendly

Tags: javascript, seo, widget, web-crawler

I am trying to create a widget that my customers can use on their website. All the widget does is display news feed inside a `<div>` on the customer's website.

For example the customer would include my script on their webpage through remote source:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.widget_source.com"></script>
<div id="widget"></div>
```

Then my script would write a bunch of news feed data into the `<div>`. Since the news feed is newly added through javascript, any search crawler would not see the data and thus the page would not get SEO benefits.

My question is:

Is it possible to make the content of the news feed index-able by search engine so that my customers who use the widget would benefit from the SEO? I've looked at [Making ajax content crawlable by search engines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839055/how-to-making-ajax-content-crawlable-by-search-engines). But this doesn't work as I have no control over my customer's backend.

The widget does not necessarily need to be in javascript. Are there any other ways to achieve my goal (maybe through iframe or RSS)?

Comment: see http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/12384/how-good-is-it-for-seo-if-you-have-a-widget-that-lives-on-other-sites/12385#12385

Comment: The link is really useful but not really what I'm looking for. I'd like to improve SEO for my customers who use widget. The SEO benefit is not due to any back links but due to having dynamic news feed contents on my customer's page provided by the widget.

Comment: There is no SEO value for your visitors. At best it's duplicate content. At worse it's invisible to search engines.

Comment: 'I have no control over my customer's backend' - http://www.healthline.com/symptom/flatulence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google does index similar systems like disqus. I think this is a case that they are big enough that Google have decided to reverse engineer their javascript so they can crawl it.

I'd suspect your best bet is to use standard/common javascript techniques and libraries to increase the chances that Google can work it out.

I've not directly worked with AJAX and crawling yet but I would suspect using GET based AJAX calls would increase the chances that they will be crawled. GET indicates a read based request while POST indicates a write. Search engines avoid invoking writes.